# SQLite - How can I perform on-going incremental backup from an IN-MEMORY db to a file-system db?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, in-memory-database

I am working with an IN-MEMORY database.
When my program starts I load data from file-system db into my IN-MEMORY db.
From that point and on I work directly with the IN-MEMORY db.
This is in order to achieve high performance.

In addition, I have a requirement that my original file-system db **will be kept updated** every few seconds.

In order to achieve this I was trying to use [SQLite Online Backup API](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html). 
The idea was to have a worker-thread that will save latest modifications every few seconds:

```
void WorkerThread()
{
    // Initialize SQLite online-backup ONCE:
    p = sqlite3_backup_init(...);

    loop{
        Sleep(few seconds);

        // Save only intermediate changes (?)
        sqlite3_backup_step(p, -1); // Backup all modifications from last time

    }  while( program is running);

    // Program is exiting...
    sqlite3_backup_finish(p);
}
```

The problem I found was that this API **cannot be used successively**:
The first call to `sqlite3_backup_step()` will save the whole db, but any successive calls after some data was modified will save nothing(!).

My question:
Is there an **efficient and incremental way** to keep an external file-system db up-to-date with an IN-MEMORY db latest state? 
*Efficient and incremental* in the sense that I can call it every ~n seconds and it will save **only the latest modifications** done from last time it was saved.